# Pentaho Kettle - Error Writing to Log File

Tags: logging, pentaho, kettle

We have a Pentaho job which is working fine in our local environment but we get an error writing to the log file after deploying it and running the job using Kettle.  The error occurs in a job which has the setting 'Execute for every input row?' checked.  Below is how the logging settings is configured the path and names are variables which are being set earlier.  It is able to log to the file fine before this step.

Job Logging Configuration

[image]

This is error I get when running Kettle with log level of debug.  Inside of the failing job we are also writing to the log which I don't know if that is a bad practice.  Has anyone else come across this issue and know a resolution?

```
ProcessFiles - Log folder [file:////<ServerPath>/QA/PentahoLogs] exists.
ProcessFiles - ERROR (version 6.1.0.1-196, build 1 from 2016-04-07 12.08.49 by buildguy) : Unable to open file appender for file [${LOGFOLDER}${LOGFILENAME}_20161005.txt] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException:
ProcessFiles - There was an error while trying to open file 'file:////<ServerPath>/QA/PentahoLogs/PartImportLog_20161005.txt' for writing
ProcessFiles - Could not write to "file:////<ServerPath>/QA/PentahoLogs/PartImportLog_20161005.txt" because it is currently in use.
ProcessFiles - ERROR (version 6.1.0.1-196, build 1 from 2016-04-07 12.08.49 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException:
ProcessFiles - There was an error while trying to open file 'file:////<ServerPath>/QA/PentahoLogs/PartImportLog_20161005.txt' for writing
ProcessFiles - Could not write to "file:////<ServerPath>/QA/PentahoLogs/PartImportLog_20161005.txt" because it is currently in use.
ProcessFiles -
ProcessFiles -    at org.pentaho.di.core.logging.LogChannelFileWriter.<init>(LogChannelFileWriter.java:78)
ProcessFiles -    at org.pentaho.di.core.logging.LogChannelFileWriter.<init>(LogChannelFileWriter.java:96)
ProcessFiles -    at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.job.JobEntryJob.execute(JobEntryJob.java:552)
ProcessFiles -    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:723)
ProcessFiles -    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:864)
ProcessFiles -    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:864)
ProcessFiles -    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:864)
ProcessFiles -    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:545)
ProcessFiles -    at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.run(Job.java:435)
ProcessFiles - Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not write to "file:////<ServerPath>/QA/PentahoLogs/PartImportLog_20161005.txt" because it is currently in use.
ProcessFiles -    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.DefaultFileContent.getOutputStream(DefaultFileContent.java:475)
ProcessFiles -    at org.pentaho.di.core.vfs.KettleVFS.getOutputStream(KettleVFS.java:289)
ProcessFiles -    at org.pentaho.di.core.logging.LogChannelFileWriter.<init>(LogChannelFileWriter.java:76)
ProcessFiles -    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the log:

> ProcessFiles - Could not write to "file://///QA/PentahoLogs/PartImportLog_20161005.txt" because it is currently in use.

so it means other process is locking the txt file.

Comment: The file is not opened by any individual and this log is unique to this job only.  It seems like the job itself is creating a lock on the file and I do not know why.  I did some research and it seems like Pentaho has trouble with UNC paths which is likely the reason for failure.  When we pointed to a local drive then the issue did not occur.

Comment: try to set the route relative to the job using ${Internal.Job.Filename.Directory}${LOGFOLDER}${LOGFILENAME}

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, the log path/file is not being used by other job in same repository user or other user.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for this. I will take care of it since next time.